# How to animate the backdrop blur clip (Skia), using react native reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, skia

Okay, since last night I'm trying animate the clip from backdrop blur.

Actually it works transform the entire component, something like that:

```
const backdropBlurClip = useMemo(
    () => rrect(rect(0, 0, FORM_WIDTH, FORM_HEIGHT), 8, 8),
    [FORM_WIDTH, FORM_HEIGHT]
  );

const xBackdropBlur = useSharedValue((width / 2) - (FORM_WIDTH / 2));
const yBackdropBlur = useSharedValue(height - (FORM_HEIGHT) - (height * 0.112676056));

const transformBackdropBlur = useDerivedValue(() => [
    { translateX: xBackdropBlur.value },
    { translateY: yBackdropBlur.value },
  ]);
const backdropBlurClipKeyboardShow = () => {
    xBackdropBlur.value = withTiming((width / 2) - (FORM_WIDTH / 2), { duration: 300 });
    yBackdropBlur.value = withTiming((height / 2) - (FORM_HEIGHT / 1.2), { duration: 300 });
  }

const backdropBlurClipKeyboardHide = () => {
    xBackdropBlur.value = withTiming((width / 2) - (FORM_WIDTH / 2), { duration: 500 });
    yBackdropBlur.value = withTiming(height - (FORM_HEIGHT) - (height * 0.112676056), { duration: 500 });
  }
const handleKeyboardShow = () => {
    backdropBlurLocationY.value = withTiming((height / 2) - (FORM_HEIGHT / 1.2), { duration: 300 });
  }

const handleKeyboardHide = () => {
    backdropBlurLocationY.value = withTiming(height - (FORM_HEIGHT) - (height * 0.112676056), { duration: 500 });
  }

useEffect(() => {
    const onShow = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
      handleKeyboardShow();
      backdropBlurClipKeyboardShow();
    });
    const onHide = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
      handleKeyboardHide();
      backdropBlurClipKeyboardHide();
    });

    return () => {
      onShow.remove();
      onHide.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

This code will transform entire component, the next step is make only clip move but the BackdropBlur component receives a prop called clip with type AnimatedProp<ClipDef | undefided> i.e. the core of my question is... how can I make AnimatedStyle works in this context?